# Firebase/Hosting. Can't run: firebase init

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

On Firebase I want to try Hosting and see how it works.
I may actually have used this in the past, but quite a while ago and when it was different.

Here is my problem. When I try to run this command:

```
firebase init
```

I get the following error in the terminal:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

I have run this command:

```
firebase login
```

as the previous command, so I don't know which "authentication credential" is missing.

Does anyone know the way to deal with this issue?

Comment: What if you do `firebase logout` and then `firebase login`

Comment: Yes, it worked. It seems like "firebase login" from zero initialized a few important things. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to logout and login again, with

```
firebase logout
```

followed by

```
firebase login
```

FYI, you will find the list of CLI's Administrative Commands here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#administrative_commands